# application.yml is not getting overriden by application-local.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

I have a SB application. Here are my configurations :

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${ACTIVE_PROFILE}

aws:
  paramstore:
    enabled: true
    prefix: /abc
    name: xyz/jkl/wer
```

Then I have the below `application.yml` where I intend to keep common properties :

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${DB_URL}
    username: ${DB_USER}
    password: ${DB_PASS}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  flyway:
    baseline-on-migrate: true

hibernate:
  dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  show_sql: true
  #format_sql: true
  #default_schema: operations

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,info,metrics,env,flyway
  endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true
  health:
    livenessState:
      enabled: true
    readinessState:
      enabled: true
```

Then I have env specific **application-local.yml :**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?useSSL=false
    username: postgres
    password: abc
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  flyway:
    baseline-on-migrate: true

hibernate:
  dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  show_sql: true
  #format_sql: true
  #default_schema: operations

# logback
logging:
  level:
    root: debug
```

When I run the application I pass the env variable :**${ACTIVE_PROFILE}**  as  **local**.

I get this error on running the app :

```
nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, ${DB_URL}
```

Active Profile from Log :

```
The following 1 profile is active: "local"
```

When I remove the db specific properties from application.yml, I get the below error :

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (the profiles local are currently active).
```

**UPDATE:**

I dont have the below configured for local, that is why I am overriding them in `application-local.yml`. But for higher env I have them configured.

```
url: ${DB_URL}
username: ${DB_USER}
password: ${DB_PASS}
```

What I am expecting is `application-local.yml` file should override the `application.yml` file but I am not sure why `application-local.yml` is not getting read at all and why the properties are being taken from `application.yml` instead.